# Can not Rewrite a URL with my .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble rewriting a URL on my website to make it more presentable and easier to find on search engines.

**I want to turn this:**
 `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/threads/index?threadName=Glitches`

**Into this:**
 `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/threads/Glitches`

**I'm currently using a .htaccess file with this in it:**
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^threads/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /threads/threadName=$1   [NC,L]`

From what I've seen seen in other questions, this should work.

**What goes wrong:**

When I type `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/threads/Glitches` into the URL, it just gives me a 404 error saying that the page is missing. From my understanding it should load `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/threads/index?threadName=Glitches`, but with the changed URL. Though I might be misunderstanding that.

Any help is appreaciated.
Thanks

Comment: Explain the "isn't working" part with a screencast, detailed folder relations, input URLs and logs, better yet a RewriteLog perhaps.

Comment: The target in your rule is wrong. Furthermore it should point to `threads/index.php?...` at least. Better yet, use an assertion `(?!index)[A-Za-z...]+`, so it won't loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO

(I cheated and used Google but amended the info according to your question.)

Source : [How To Set Up Mod_Rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^thread/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ threads/index?threadName=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: @EthanLewis Maybe try one of the more simple examples in that link just to ensure that mod_rewrite is working on your server? Maybe your host does not allow you to make use of .htaccess files, maybe you need to configure this, there are many variables here to take into consideration but either of the answers provided here should work?

Comment: I did as you suggested and the mod_rewrite worked just fine in the examples, but when I try the two solutions I just keep getting the errors. It's very perplexing.

Comment: @EthanLewis You notice that `threads/index?threadName=$1` does not have a leading /?

Comment: @EthanLewis Tested the url rewrite on my end and it works, the end result is that you'd be able to use `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/thread/Glitches` or `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/threads/index?threadName=Glitches` to access the page however in your code you will use the SEO links. Notice how I used thread and not threads, might be the issue.

Comment: so you tested it with `RewriteRule ^thread/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ threads/index?threadName=$1 [NC]` and and you were able to access  `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/thread/Glitches` without any errors?

Comment: @EthanLewis On my local environment and in a .htaccess file yes but you must have `RewriteEngine on` directly before that.

Comment: This is my entire .htaccess file:

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^thread/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ threads/index?threadName=$1 [NC]` and I access it with `http://www.gamingpopulace.com/thread/Glitches` but I still get the 404 error.

Comment: @EthanLewis Check your apache error logs, should say something about why. This is maybe due to your code not loading the content via said url or something of that nature?

Comment: @EthanLewis You must have the logs in your control panel or somewhere on the server if you ftp in, ask your host to help you to locate them. It's the only way you will know why you are getting a 404.

Comment: OK I've gotten the error logs up and there are quite a few errors. Anything that I should look for in particular?

Comment: @EthanLewis Make a request to that page, then  right after the request go and look at the last log value. It should tell you why there was the error and will likely have a reason as to why this is not working for you?

Comment: I think there must be a problem in one of the pages on my site. I would most probably have to redo quite a bit to fix the mistake, so I will leave it for now and come back to it when I plan on redesigning my site. Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/` from this `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$`

Replace

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^threads/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /threads/threadName=$1   [NC,L]
```

with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^threads/([^/]*)?$ /threads/threadName=$1    [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but when I do this I receive an internal Server Error.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. If it helps I'm updating the site live at http://www.gamingpopulace.com/, so you can see the same errors that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your original url is working, try this in root dir,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^threads/([\w-]+)?$ threads/index?threadName=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
```